# GnuPG/GPGee shell integration on windows 7 64-bit

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, gnupg

Has anyone found a working solution to integrate a GnuPG in windows 7 ? I'm specifically looking for functionality similar to GPGee (right click on encrypted file -> Decrypt). I'm having trouble getting GPGee to work under Windows 7 64bit.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 2):

How about GPG4Win?

This foreign lanugage screen shoot appears to show the right click context menu you wanted although I can't read german.  The software fully supports English as well.
[image]

Quote from http://www.gpg4win.org/features.html
"System Requirements
Gpg4win supports Windows 7."